# Associated entity is not loaded properly in test environment but works in dev (Symfony 5 + Doctrine 2)

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, phpunit, symfony5

I have an `User` that has `Place`s. It's a @OneToMany relation.
It's mapped as follows:

```php
#User.php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Place::class, mappedBy="owner", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $places;

/**
 * @return Collection|Place[]
 */
public function getPlaces(): Collection
{
    return $this->places;
}
```

```php
#Place.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="places")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Groups ({"place_read", "place_write"})
 */
private $owner;
```

When testing a method that calls some other method that tried to invoke `$user->getPlaces()` the collection returns empty.

```php
//empty when in test environment
$places1 = $user->getPlaces();

//works in both dev or test
$places2 = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Place::class)->findBy(['owner' => $user]);
```

In my phpunit test method I'm calling `self::bootKernel()`, etc, but it seems something is not being loaded in order to load the collection properly.
I also tries to XDebug the phpunit test, and could confirm the user has places assigned to him in the test database, and the `doctrine:schema:validate --env=test` also has nothing wrong to show.

If I call `$user->getPlaces()` in a controller for example, it also works as expected.

My test looks like this:

```php
public function testSubscribe()
{
    self::bootKernel();
    $container = static::getContainer();
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $customer = $this->createRandomUser();
    $merchant = $this->createRandomUser();
    $place = $this->createRandomPlace($merchant);
    $plan = $em->getRepository(Plan::class)->find(4);
    $paypal = $container->get(Paypal::class);
    $subs = $paypal->subscribe($merchant, $plan); //this method calls another one that uses $user->getPaces()
}
```

What I am missing here?

I'm using Symfony 5.3.9 + Doctrine 2.10.2.

Comment: Typo just in the question or is it also in your test? `$plan = $em->getRepository(Plan::class)->find(4)` is missing the semi-colon `;`

Comment: After calling `$place = $this->createRandomPlace($merchant);`, what does `dd($merchant);` output? Would also like to see the code for `$this->createRandomPlace()`, as you're not explicitly calling `$merchant->addPlace($place);` in the `testSubscribe()` method.

Comment: Hi @WillB..
The missing `;`was just a typo here when selecting the code to paste.

1. dd($merchant) it brings the customer and also shows the relationship between places and the merchant. However, dd($merchant->getPlaces()->count()) brings me `0`. But adding a breakpoint at this line, I can see the place was created and is associated to $merchant in mysql.

2. Code for createRandomPlace - https://pastebin.com/Tu4EnhYU

3. ->addPlace... good point, but the method above sets the owner of the place

Comment: Btw, by adding ->addPlace($place) in the test method, makes it work as expected, although there's no changes in the db. Why it's not automatically related when I create the place setting the owner property?

Comment: Cascading within the Doctrine entity would need to be set to `cascade={"persist", "merge"}` without explicitly calling `$em->persist($owner)` in `createRandomUser()`. While `Place::setOwner()` is called, does `setOwner()` add the place to the User via `$user->addPlace($this)`, which may be triggering the orphan removal.

Comment: I have the same problem in my tests except that in my case it seems to come from loading fixtures using alice and liip, example here https://github.com/CedCannes/sf_bug_collections_empty_during_tests_with_fixtures

Answer (score 0):

I add an answer as this bug is still here (I discovered it thanks to my code coverage report), with the following stack:

- symfony/framework-bundle": "6.2.*
- "hautelook/alice-bundle": "^2.11
- "theofidry/alice-data-fixtures": "1.6.0"

As proposed by [Ced](https://github.com/CedCannes/sf_bug_collections_empty_during_tests_with_fixtures), a quick fix is to clear the entity manager before running your test:

```
$client = self::createClient();
$client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager()->clear();
$client->request('GET', '/my-route');
```